# How do I reset value for a variable passed from loop without set_fact ANSIBLE?

Tags: loops, ansible, yaml

I have a loop that passes application name as follows"

```yaml
- name: Loop for each application
  include: main.yml APPLICATION = "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ applications_from_ansible_survery }}
```

The problem I have is once the APPLICATION variable is used in the main.yml, I will have to change that variable if the application name is WiinZip instead of WinZip. Example:

```yaml
- name: Change if error in application name
  set_fact: 
    APPLICATION: "WinZip"
  when: APPLICATION == "WiinZip"
```

When the loop iterates to the next app, as you can see, the APPLICATION variable is stuck with WinZip and does not move on to the next application due to set_fact. How do I fix this ? How do I UNSET this APPLICATION variable back to empty, or how do I force the APPLICATION variable to take the next item in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work using the same var name in the above case. As you can see on the [Ansible variable precedence documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence), variables defined in `set_fact` have a higher priority than task vars so the value is actually overridden after the first task is run.

Moreover, fixing this kind of expected typo at run time in a task is probably not the best strategy (bad performance, hard to scale/maintain). I would approach this by fixing the known typos directly in the list prior to actually looping in my task.

In this example playbook, I'm listing the known typos and their correction in a dictionary and replacing every entry which matches

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    applications_from_ansible_survey:
      - WiinZip
      - LibreOffice
      - Timz

    known_typos:
      WiinZip: WinZip
      WinZiip: WinZip
      Teas: Teams
      Timz: Teams

    matching_typos: "{{ applications_from_ansible_survey | select('in', known_typos) }}"

    fixed_list: >
      {{
        matching_typos | map('extract', known_typos)
        +
        applications_from_ansible_survey | difference(matching_typos)
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: debug initial var for example
      debug:
        var: applications_from_ansible_survey

    - name: loop over the fixed list
      debug:
        var: APPLICATION
      loop: "{{ fixed_list }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: APPLICATION
```

This gives as a result:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug initial var for example] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "applications_from_ansible_survey": [
        "WiinZip",
        "LibreOffice",
        "Timz"
    ]
}

TASK [loop over the fixed list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=WinZip) => {
    "APPLICATION": "WinZip",
    "ansible_loop_var": "APPLICATION"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Teams) => {
    "APPLICATION": "Teams",
    "ansible_loop_var": "APPLICATION"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=LibreOffice) => {
    "APPLICATION": "LibreOffice",
    "ansible_loop_var": "APPLICATION"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the potential solution - I was wondering, is there a way to NULL out the APPLICATION variable before the next iteration ?

Comment: Yes but then null value will override the value you set inside your task since it is set as a fact. Basically this is not how you deal with variables in ansible. You are on the wrong way. Since you do not give any background info on what you are really doing in your included file, it's hard to put you on a right track.

Comment: I am working with a very inconsistent infrastructure, and I realize this is not the right way to do things.... but I have to work with what I have. For my task, i just wanted to know if I can empty out that variable before the next loop iteration... that is the only thing I need... it is a predefined loop list that I cannot change and I cannot create another list on my own....